# Firestore unexpected query results

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query:

```
 collection("events")
            .orderBy("location.geohash")
            .where("location.geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: geohashStart)
            .where("location.geohash", isLessThanOrEqualTo: geohashEnd)
            .orderBy("startTime")
            .startAt([fromTime]).endAt([toTime]);
```

The intention is to get all events between geohashStart and geohashEnd, and then return events only in the time range [fromTime, toTime]. I used startAt, endAt because firestore doesn't allow inequality conditions on multiple fields.

---

When I run this query with fromTime 1681336800000, toTime 1681423140000 it doesn't return any results.

Observation 1: If I remove the startAt and endAt from the original query I do get the following event startTime list (so these are all the events between those 2 geohashes):

```
[1681327944696, 1681371253853]
```

Observation 2: If I remove just the endAt from the original query I still get the following startTime list (I was expecting it to return just `[1681371253853]` though):

```
[1681327944696, 1681371253853]
```

Observation 3: startAfter and endBefore behave the same.

I was expecting the original query to return `[1681371253853]`, as it falls between fromTime and toTime.

I am running Firestore Emulator locally.

What could be the reason for such behaviour? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A Firestore query can only contain range conditions on a single field. From the Firestore documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Under the hood, both `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo`/`isLessThanOrEqualTo` and `startAt`/`endAt` are range filters, so your query is trying to perform a range filter on two fields which isn't possible.

You will have to perform one of these filters in your application code.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the Firestore Emulator didn't throw an error in this case?

Comment: Nope, that indeed seems odd. It might be worth filing an issue on the GitHub repo for it.

Comment: After reading your response, I tried this query (it is supposed to be valid according to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#set_cursor_based_on_multiple_fields)).


`collection.orderBy("location.geohash").orderBy('startTime').startAt([geohashStart, fromTime]).endAt([geohashEnd, toTime])`


And yet it still returned all the events, instead of returning just `[1681371253853]`. Do you know why it behaves like this? From the documentation it is supposed to work (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: I presented the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76007052/4384593) but in a more detailed format.

Comment: I didn't repost the same problem. If you look at the new post, it is related to the current one and yet different. The query I mentioned above just fit into the other topic as well. So I find it needed a separate thread.

Comment: I supposed I shouldn't have mentioned the other question and I didn't move on to another problem. I would like to have an answer to both. They are two topics. And, no, my understanding didn't change, I am more confused now on both topics.

Comment: The answer here is that the code you shared can't work because you perform have range clauses on multiple fields, and Firestore can only perform a range filter on a single field. Using `startAt`/`endAt` makes no difference for that, as it translates into the same clause as `>=` and `<=` in the backend.