# How do Firestore startAt(), endAt(), startAfter(), endAfter() actually work?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Example 1 (string type)**

I have the following geohashes stored as strings in my Firestore database:

```
u281wpz796, u281xk3j2w, u281xp5ydz, u281ygyc6c, u281zdxqr5, u281zn0xrv, u2838s1msj, u283bmrdnd
```

Let's run this query:

```
collection("events")
            .orderBy("location.geohash")
            .startAt([geohashStart])
            .endAt([geohashEnd])
```

If I run the above query for `geohashStart=u281h` and `geohashEnd = u281~`, the query returns the correct list of geohashes:

```
u281wpz796, u281xk3j2w, u281xp5ydz, u281ygyc6c, u281zdxqr5, u281zn0xrv
```

---

**Example 2 (number type)**

I've tried a similar example but this time with event startTime which is stored as milliseconds numbers in the database.

Here are all the event startTimes:

```
1681122748378, 1681336740000, 1681122320785, 1681122603079, 1681122389346, 1681122511280, 1681327944696, 1681371253853
```

Query:

```
collection("events")
          .orderBy("startTime")
          .startAt([fromTime])
          .endAt([toTime])
```

If I run the above query with `fromTime=1681336800000` and `toTime=1681423140000`, then it will correctly return the result of `[1681371253853]`.

---

**Example 3 (combining both)**

Given the geohashes and startTimes mapped 1-to-1 in the same order as presented in the above 2 examples.

Query:

```
collection('events').orderBy("location.geohash")
                    .orderBy("startTime")
                    .startAt([geohashStart, fromTime])
                    .endAt([geohashEnd, toTime])
```

If I run this query for `geohashStart=u2830` `geohashEnd=u283h` & `startTime=1681336800000` `endTime=1681423140000`, it will return the following startTimes `1681327944696, 1681371253853` (which seems to be incorrect).

Given the behaviour from Example 1 and Example 2 I was expecting to only get the result `[1681371253853]`, as here I am also giving parameters to startAt / endAt which are not an exact match, yet it seems to only apply for the 1st parameter (geohashStart, geohashEnd), the 2nd  parameter (fromTime, toTime) being ignored for some reason.

---

Could you please explain me why the Example 1 and Example 2 queries work? And why does the 3rd Example return an incorrect result?

I suppose same question would apply if I used `startAfter()` / `endAfter()`.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#set_cursor_based_on_multiple_fields) only shows examples where `startAt` parameter exactly matches the value in the row.

Yet, in my examples, for the geohash query (Example 1) the inputs are geohash prefixes (so not an exact match), while for the startTime query (Example 2) the inputs are not exact matches with the existing values. And yet Example 3 seems to behave differently.

Comment: i'm having the same problem: the second query parameter is ignored by startAt. Couldn't find any documentation nor examples about this issue... Could it be a bug?